# There is a space after latex \ref{}, how to solve this problem？

Tags: spacing, graphics

```
\documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\section{Sample for first level head}\label{sec1}

Figure \ref{fig1}\subref{x} ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.

\begin{figure}[htbp]  
  \centering   
  
  \subfloat[] 
    {
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering     
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{empty}\label{x} 
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    \subfloat[] 
    {
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{empty}\label{x} 
        \end{minipage}
    }%
    
\caption{This is the sample figure caption.\label{fig1}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is the problem I have when using the weliy template. When referencing a subgraph, there will be a space between the mothergraph icon and the subgraph icon. How to solve this problem? And even if I add a space between \ref{} and \subref{}, the distance will not increase.Can 1 (a) become 1(a) by reference?

Comment: try with the article class. If the space disappear complain to the author of your class (which is not in texlive and so can't be tested.)

Comment: but I checked with the class and can't reproduce the problem. Is your tex system up-to-date?

Comment: I can't reproduce it with the copy of the class I have, dated 2017/06/23. What's your version? And, if different, where can it be downloaded from?

Comment: Using the article class can solve this problem, but this way I can't use the template. I am using VScode+texlive2021. kpathsea version is 6.3.3.

Comment: kpathsea is irrelevant. Check the version of the class in your log-file.

Comment: Do you mean to open the log file of the class with Notepad? It says "Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class" Is this what you mean? Or you can download this template at "https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/page/journal/10982760/homepage/forauthors.html?5"

Comment: Show your complete log file (that is the file with the same name as your tex file but with the extension `.log` , copy it into the question or put it somewhere for download. And learn to ping people if you want that they get notified if you comment.